# AngularJS - text input value not reflecting in scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input text field as :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" name="uservalue" ng-model="inputNumber" ng-required="true" autofocus="true" ng-blur="checkIfValid()"/>
```

My controller has the ng-blur function as follows:

```
$scope.checkIfValid = function(){
        console.log("Value is = " + $scope.inputNumber);
}
```

I have defined - `$scope.inputNumber = '';`

My console.log shows an empty value even though I input a value in the text field and hit 'Tab' or move on to the next field to invoke the ng-blur function.

What am I doing wrong here?
`

Comment: Possible plunker ?

Comment: try with ng-change instead ng-blur for debug purposes. also +1 for a plunker detailing the problem.

Comment: agreed on a plunker - how are the controller/directives tied together?

Comment: Does your console displays `Value is = ` or does it not display anything?

Comment: You should try `keyup` instead of `blur`.

Comment: I tried exactly the same code of yours, and it works in my local. So, I agree with @KaushalNiraula that you should check if the function`checkIfValid()` is called.

Comment: 1) Did you by any chance forget to add `ng-app` and `ng-controller `? 2) Change `ng-blur` to `ng-change`. 3) add a `$watch` for `inputValue` and see if it displays anything in the log

Comment: The plunker seems to be working fine - it's something in my code - I can see the "Value is = " in my console.log .. i need to work with ng-blur because I need to send the entire text input to my API. Not sure what I am missing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputNumber="new";
  
  $scope.checkIfValid = function(){
        console.log("Value is = " + $scope.inputNumber);
}
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">  
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" name="uservalue" ng-model="inputNumber" ng-required="true" autofocus="true" ng-blur="checkIfValid()"/>
    
    <h1>{{inputNumber}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though your answer is correct - this is what worked for me :

I passed inputNumber as a parameter to checkifValid(inputNumber) and then the value enters my controller, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hi,  i didnot get ,  you want to pass value as parameter

Comment: Yeah - I passed the ng-model as a parameter , and that worked - I can get the value now in my controller .. but $scope.inputNumber doesn't seem to be binding to the value in input in the text box - any idea why?